# How do I access my S3 With my EC2 instance on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, cloud

I have an web application where i want to put my static content on s3 bucket. I need to access my s3 content with my Ec2 Instance. S3 bucket may contain image, songs and videos. I need to show all the content of S3 buckets on websites.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access it by *ssh-ing* into the EC2 instance, you can use the [aws s3 cli](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/) or [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd).

If you want to include S3 content in a website and make it publicly visible, note that you can access your S3 files using HTTP ([see here for instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html)):

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/filepath/filename
```

Comment: i want to know how do i manage S3 Content with EC2 Intance. Like I want to upload image or download a image from S3 bucket using Ec2. How do i do that?

Comment: What do you mean by *using EC2*?

Comment: i want to manage the content of S3 with php Api install in EC2 Server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the AWS SDK for PHP to manage your S3...
[PHP S3 SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-s3.html)

```
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-s3.html
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to interact with S3 directly from your PHP code, you are probably looking the [sdk for PHP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/) provided by aws.

This SDK permits you to directly interact with AWS components. The [documentation for S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html).